# TouchesMoved lags more in iOS8?

Tags: performance, ios7, uiview, xamarin.ios, ios8

I'm battling with iOS 8 performance problems.  Updating to iOS 8 has literally made my application near unusable on iPad 2's.  There are some fundamental performance issues that I'm trying to iron out to see if I can avoid them or at least lessen the effect of them on my application.  One problem is dragging UIImageViews.  There's something very different about how the TouchesMoved function gets called with UIImageViews.

[Please see my video below for a full description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP1BWweCAio), but here are my current findings.  I'm using the TouchesMoved function in UIImageViews to drag objects across the screen when the user drags his finger across the screen.

```
    public override void TouchesMoved (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved (touches, evt);

        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
        PointF TouchLocation_old = TouchLocation;
        TouchLocation = touch.LocationInView (this.Superview);
//      Console.WriteLine("TouchLocation = " + TouchLocation);

        float offsetX = TouchLocation.X - TouchLocation_old.X;
        float offsetY = TouchLocation.Y - TouchLocation_old.Y;
        Center = new PointF(Center.X + offsetX, Center.Y + offsetY);
    }
```

In my project, as soon as i modify the position of the object i'm dragging, there seems to be some sort of delay or throttle to the TouchesMoved Event.  Normally, the TouchesMoved event goes of every couple milliseconds, but in iOS 8 in some situations it's going off every 120 ms causing lag spikes when dragging objects across the screen.  Why is this?  What about iOS 8 and the TouchesMoved function has changed

Additional note, I've noticed that a large number of UIViews added to the view controller causes this.  For some reason in iOS 7, adding a large number of UIViews to the view controller didn't effect it as much, but in iOS 8 it causes the TouchesMoved function to be called less frequently (possibly because it's iterating through all of the views to determine if it's touching them?  But iOS 7 would have done that too right?  Did something in iOS 8 make that process more time consuming?)  I've also noticed UIScrollViews become "heavier" and "slower" much quicker in iOS 8 as well, where as in iOS 7 they were working smoothly with that same number of subviews.

----Added hardware info----

iPad 2 MC969LL/A on iOS 7.1.2

iPad Mini MD528LL/A on iOS 8.0

----Added findings----

in iOS 8, large numbers of UIViews within your View Controller's View are lagging the performance of CAKeyframeAnimation's as well.  Though this test case isn't as extreme as seen in my application, I've proven this TouchesMoved issue out in an isolated test case below.

[Video demoing the project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muXJZ76sNm0)

[Xamarin Studio Project via Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r39de35p72t1g4e/TestIOS7vsIOS8%202.zip?dl=0)

Comment: DID YOU EVER FIND A SOLUTION?!?!? I've been struggling with this for months!

Comment: I had to make my code more efficient and adjust to the issues. It took a solid week of work though. It's just proof that each new iOS version is slower and requires more resources than before. Apple just keeps adding more and more features that slow everything down. And older devices become sludge once they update.

Comment: When you say "make my code more efficient" you are basically saying that your framerate was dropping?

Comment: @prototypical so my theory at the time was, iOS is iterating through every single view during a touch event (begin, move, end, etc). And that new iOS version dramatically slowed that iteration process. So I had to basically have less views on my view controller and on my collection view cells. I optimized the views by removing certain views from superview when they were out of sight. Then adding them back when they were about to be used. So rather than setting something to Hidden = True, actually removed it from superview all together.